# How to remotely view html files using OSGI

Tags: java, html, http, browser, osgi

I am very new to enterprise technologies and web development and my current project has me stuck in a tough spot. I am using OSGI and trying to use HelpGUI [my previous OSGI question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761383/my-html-hyperlinks-do-not-work-in-my-osgi-bundle) and I cannot get a 3rd party library to display my html files from Java. Instead can I use OSGI or some other library to host those html files locally? I could then use Java to pop open a browser that points to the index.html on localhost right?

Let me know if my train of thought is sound. I googled for tutorials, but they take me down paths which I believe are overly complicated or do not get my html files available to the browser. Can someone start me in the right direction?

Comment: You can always (well, pretty much always) open a browser on the client, but that will require you to put resources in a place a regular browser can reach it, like the file system or even an embedded servlet container (I think that is what Eclipse does). To be able to use it from within the JVM (like HelpGui), I think you'll need to register a custom URLStreamHandlerFactory which can delegate resolving the URL's to the OSGi environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple way of doing this.

You need to host the html files inside OSGi and publish them over HTTP.

1. Hosting
   One option (probably the simplest one) is to package them inside the jar of your bundle.
2. Publish over HTTP

The OSGi spec includes a small embedded web server and an API for publishing content in it.
The related service you need to use is called HttpService. Check the OSGi specification or the javadoc of the HTTPService to see how to use it. 
You can publish servlets or plain resources - for your case the latter is enough.
You have to provide a short HttpContext class, which knows how to find your html files - e.g. by using

public URL getResource(String name) {
  return (getClass().getResource(name));
}

You can check the HTTP Demo available in [ProSyst's mBedded Server](http://dz.prosyst.com/pdoc/mBS_SDK/um/runtime/osgi/docs/framework/index.html) - it does exactly what you need.

Note that in some OSGi frameworks the HTTP Service maybe won't be installed by default - check what additional bundles are available in the installation and whether you have to install smth additional to make it available in the OSGi registry.